# How can I disassemble this kitchen faucet for repairs?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

My kitchen faucet recently started leaking, but I've not been able to find instructions on addressing this problem that will work with my faucet.
I don't know the make of model of the faucet as it is unmarked and was already installed when I bought my place.

Following basic DIY faucet leak instructions, I can turn the hot and cold water lines off and remove the aerator from the stem. Typically, these instructions then say to remove any caps on the handles (*there don't appear to be any*) and/or remove screws from the handles (*again, don't appear to be any*) to remove the handles and get to the canisters.

Has anyone seen a faucet like this and, if so, do you have any recommendations about how to get the handles off/where to go from here?

I should note I wanted to do my due diligence with trying to fix this faucet, but I hate it. There's no pull out hose, the hot water handle turns on clockwise, the cold water handle turns on counter clockwise, and the handles are impossible to clean. If the consensus is this faucet is un-salvageable, I have no problem getting a replacement that works better.

Here is what the front, side, above, and below the faucet/faucet handles look like:

[image: Front of faucet]

[image: Faucet handle side]

[image: Faucet handle from above]

[image: Faucet handle from below]

Comment: Interesting!  You really do seem to have covered all the typical points where a fastener would be hidden.  I think this is called a cross-head faucet? Does the beveled ring where the swoopy curved bit of the main faucet joins into the main body move at all?  It looks like there may be a nut hidden under there?

Comment: Shot in the dark, Perhaps one of the nubs on the handles can be unscrewed to reveal a set screw?

Comment: @IronEagle [I think you may have figured it out](https://imgur.com/a/6UPe9Ti). It is so hard to look back there and I didn't think to look on the main body but you guessed it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you as well. If this nubs were hiding the set screw, I would almost be ok with how hard it makes the handles to clean. Almost.

Comment: If you don't like the faucet anyway and don't mind buying a new one, why bother wasting time trying to fix it?  You also didn't mention where it's leaking from. If I had to guess, a washer in the handle has worn out and doesn't allow it to completely shut off tightly and drips from the head? (most common)

Comment: @Phaelaxz because I want to learn. Your guess is what I was suspicious of based on my research. It is leaking from the head. It's why I was trying to get the handles off and got stuck looking for the screw to detach them.